# Tips on creating a Netflix-style scrolling menu in CSS/PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

Working on a website which will allow members to catalog, shelve and review books. Right now, the main screen shows images of the book covers, plus basic info about the book. The books fill the screen and then wrap to the next line.

What I want to do is have a "Netflix-style" interface. i.e. First row=contemporary romance, second row=westerns, third row=vampires/werewolves, etc. And the row displays the first few books in that category, with arrows to scroll right and left to be shown other books.

Wondering if there are any examples of anything like this out there?  Here is the [site](http://www.lusciousreads.com/). Be advised these are romance-style books, so the book covers shown may be "racy" although not indecent or pornographic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to create a "container" element with `position: relative;` (to allow absolute positioning inside of it) and `overflow: hidden;` to hide the track.

Inside of this, place a "track" element with `position: absolute;` and `width: 2000px;` or however crazy wide it needs to be.

Inside the track, your book elements should be placed with `float: left;` and an appropriate `margin-right` value.

Two absolutely-positioned elements should act as the left and right sliders. A javascript `setInterval` can check whether the mouse is hovering over them every 10 milliseconds or so. If it is, change the `left` css property of the "track" element to slide it left or right.

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2x6s/3/) to illustrate this. Obviously, more complex code could be added to check whether the track has reached the edge, but you get the gist of it.